# Ruby - hash to array

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
a =  [{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('569a58b8e301d083c300000c')}]
```

and I want it to be:

```
[BSON::ObjectId('569a58bee301d083c3000752')]
```

I was experimenting with

```
a.map{|e| e.map{|k, v| v }}
```

but it gives me nested array:

```
[[BSON::ObjectId('569a58b8e301d083c300000c')]]
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just had a hash:

```
h = {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('569a58b8e301d083c300000c')}
```

and you wanted to fetch the `BSON::ObectId`, you would call `Hash#[]`:

```
h["_id"] #=> BSON::ObjectId('569a58b8e301d083c300000c')
```

The same works with `map`:

```
a.map { |h| h["_id"] }
#=> [BSON::ObjectId('569a58b8e301d083c300000c')]
```

Comment: Thank you, stupid of me not to think about that. Have a nice day!

Comment: Not just `[a.first["_id"]]`?

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution.

```
a = [{"id"=>"1234"},{"id"=>"9876"}]
a.flat_map(&:values)
=> ["1234", "9876"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use values, then call flatten.

```
a.collect(:&values).flatten
```

Or, if there'll only ever be one value

```
a[0].values[0]
```